# Has anyone successfully implemented the dojox.mobile.carousel in XPages

Tags: xpages, dojox.mobile, mobile-controls

I have a requirement for an application in a Domino version 9.x deployment for a carousel like interface similar to what Netflix and others use to allow continuous scrolling. I got the jQuery jCarousel code working from [here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/). But that lacks the pizzazz the user wants since the swiping feature is not available. I also used 100% computed HTML instead of being able to intersperse XPages controls within the carousel code.

So I found [dojox/mobile/carousel](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/Carousel) (examples [here](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileCatalog/demo.html)) but all implementations, including the basic examples are not working well. The number of elements does not seem to be flexible and the positioning of them is much lower than I would think the should be. I fiddled with the CSS to see if I could fix things but have not found the right combination.

Here is the entire custom control I am using for this test (I captured the images from the demo and added them as image resources):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    dojoParseOnLoad="true">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:metaData
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        </xp:metaData>
        <xp:metaData
            name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"
            content="yes">
        </xp:metaData>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot/dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css">
        </xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dojox/mobile"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dojox/mobile/parser"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule
            name="dojox/mobile/Carousel"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:panel>Above it</xp:panel>
    <div
        id="carousel1"
        data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Carousel"
        data-dojo-props='height:"150px", navButton:false, numVisible:2, title:"Category"'>
        <!-- View #1 -->
        <div
            data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SwapView">
            <div
                data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/CarouselItem"
                data-dojo-props='src:"dish1.jpg", value:"dish", headerText:"dish"'></div>
            <div
                data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/CarouselItem"
                data-dojo-props='src:"glass1.jpg", value:"glass", headerText:"glass"'></div>
        </div>
        <!-- View #2 -->
        <div
            data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SwapView">
            <div
                data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/CarouselItem"
                data-dojo-props='src:"stone1.jpg", value:"stone", headerText:"stone"'></div>
            <div
                data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/CarouselItem"
                data-dojo-props='src:"shell1.jpg", value:"shell", headerText:"shell"'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <xp:panel>Below it</xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

in the sample in the documentation it has this comment followed by the inclusion of a JavaScript file.

```
<!-- Need to load the theme files for Carousel and PageIndicator as well as the base theme file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"
        data-dojo-config="mblThemeFiles: ['base','Carousel','PageIndicator']"></script>
```

Not having this step done may be my problem but I cannot see how to do that within the XPages environment.

Comment: Bootstrap has a carousel as well

Answer (score 0):

The dojo carousel exists since 1.7 Notes 8.5.3 comes with 1.6 (i dont know the dojo version of Notes9), so you maby have to update your dojo or implement a newer dojo lib in your application.

I did a short experiment on it, i disabled the build in dojo adding `xsp.client.script.libraries=none` to my `xsp.properties` and importet the dojo 1.9 in my application under WEB-INF/dojo/... then add the dojo to my xPage as ClientSide script resource. As soon i finished this the programatic Example from the [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/Carousel.html#dojox-mobile-carousel) homepage worked immediately with out bigger errors (forgot to change the image sources =) ..).

The problem when adding `xsp.client.script.libraries=none` to your `xsp.properties` is that you also disable the XSP. library and some other xPage features wich you have to rebuild using the newer dojo version.

I realy prefer using dojo over jquery but in this case If you dont want to update your dojo i recomend you to maby stay at the jquery [Library](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples) for this or look for other solutions.

Comment: This is for a version 9.x deployment